# How to replace chars and keep string length?

Tags: javascript, regex

Is possible in js transform a String in this format

```
123456789
```

In something like this

```
*****6789
```

I want to use just one statment, something like this but keeping the last four characters.

```js
var a = "12312312312123".replace(/[0-9]/g, "*")
console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you could make use of `.(?=.{4})` with `g` flag:

```js
var a = "12312312312123".replace(/.(?=.{4})/g, '*')
console.log(a)
```

Comment: Awesome. Good job.

Comment: I don't understand how, but this works amazingly well.

Answer (score 1):

Split the input into substrings, perform the replacement on the first part, and then append the second part.

```js
var input = "123-456-7890";
var prefix = input.substr(0, input.length - 4);
var suffix = input.substr(-4);
var masked = prefix.replace(/\d/g, '*');
var a = masked + suffix;
console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use padStart

```
const str = '123456789';
console.log(str.slice(-4).padStart(str.length, '*'));
```

Or

```
const str = '123456789';
console.log(str.substr(-4).padStart(str.length, '*'));
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach... by creating two capture groups and replacing the first with `*` repeated.

```js
const a = '123456789'.replace(/(^\d+)(\d{4}$)/, (m,g1,g2) => '*'.repeat(g1.length) + g2);
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use either the function `slice` or function `substr` and the function [`padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) to fill `*` from left-to-right.

```js
let str = "1234567893232323232";
console.log(str.slice(5, str.length).padStart(str.length, '*'));
```

Comment: This replaces the first 5 characters in the string with '*'. This will fail for strings  "123456789012345" or any other strings with length more than 9.